# Are some PROJ.4 projections missing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I am using QGIS 3.16.8 on Windows 10 (64). I have tried to apply the Apian II (aka Arago) projection with:

```
+proj=apian2 +lon_0=0 +lat_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs
```

but the validation step failed with:

> proj_create: Error -5 (unknown projection id)

Yet apian2 is part of the PROJ.4 projections. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can add your own projections into Proj. Have you tried that?

Comment: Many thanks for the tip; I didn’t know that. Could you steer me towards some material on how to do that?

Comment: Adding projections to PROJ can be done, but you'd need to know C/C++ to do it. And to make an acceptable PR it would also need to have tests and documentation. See [S2](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/pull/2749) as a recent example of a new projection.

Comment: I use mapserver. https://mapserver.org/mapfile/projection.html. It uses proj. I have an environment variable that points to the proj_lib. In that location, there is a file called EPSG. Go into that, define your projection and assign a code that is not being used already. Then, the application will load that file when you load it up next. And your projection should be defined. If you are getting data from your database, you will also need to define it in the spatial ref tables. In postgres, you can add it with the custom id you used and put in the same params as you did for the proj settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROJ has only supported [Apian Globular I (`apian`)](https://proj.org/operations/projections/apian.html). What source says it has `apian2`?

A related archived library named [libproject / libproj4](https://github.com/rouault/libproj4) has [`apian2`](https://github.com/rouault/libproj4/search?q=apian2), so it's possible to extend this into PROJ, which QGIS uses.

Comment: Many thanks. I am afraid I was looking at my old PROJ.4 manual written by Evenden. That still has apian2.

Comment: Yes [this one](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/blob/master/docs/old/libproj.pdf). That's for libproj4, which was separate to PROJ, although written by Evenden. I think there was some intention to merge these at some point, but that never happened.

Comment: Yes: the same Evenden. I have a 2008 draft of the document. I would love to add some projections but C/C++ is beyond my ken. Many thanks for your help.